# Is adding an image to a GET request a bad design pattern?

Tags: rest

Let me set up a very specific use case...

Let's say that you're creating a facial recognition API using Python. When you upload an image to the API at an unspecified route, you get back a list of identities that match that image... the return object is an array: `['tom', 'brad', 'john']`.

You're not uploading any data to be created or kept on the server.

You're not updating or creating anything.

What kind of request should this be? I'd assume a GET request because you're GETting the identities of the people in the uploaded image regardless of the fact that you're sending an image for processing.

Comment: I would prefer GET, as recognition is analogous to query db with some pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd assume a GET request because you're GETting the identities of the people in the uploaded image regardless of the fact that you're sending an image for processing

Sadly, no.  The problem here is that [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1), in HTTP, does describe the semantics of a message body on the request.

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

You've got the right idea - the request should be [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), so you can look at the [HTTP Method Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml) to see if there is a match.  That might lead you to SEARCH or REPORT.  These methods are extensions defined by WebDAV, and may or may not be suitable for your problem.

If it is acceptable to include the representation of the image in the query string, you could pair that with GET.  I suspect you'll run into problems with components complaining that the identifier is too long.

The TL;DR? use the POST method to deliver the image payload to the server.